# Should I move to Object Oriented Programming(black boxes) and how?

Tags: c++, oop, directx

Right now I have a DirectX engine with a couple of classes - Application,Graphics,Sound and each of them is around 1k lines and they each reference eachother.I initially tried to limit use of classes and stuff like passing the D3D Device and instead made it global for all classes to use,but I see in everyone else's engine that everything is split up into many classes and they have stuff like Engine->GetRenderer->Render(MyD3DContext); isn't that terriby inefficient?Why not just make MyD3DContext global and use it directly in the Render function.And one last thing I don't get is = how are you supposed to make classes that work independent of eachother?Sounds weird.

Comment: if your graphics is tied into your application, what do you do when you want to change your graphics? You shouldn't have to change your application just because your graphics has changed!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly why do you think that's terribly inefficient? Besides being much easier to code and maintain, that is also blazingly fast. OOP isn't a bottleneck, its a boon for large projects with multiple developers and multiple concerns(such as real world games).

Let me give you an example, since you mentioned "games":

The game is a Simulation
The simulation contains entities(Objects)
Objects can **do** things, and **have** attributes. Hence Objects are like an encapsulation of attributes and actions. This is what makes the "Object" in "Object Oriented Programming". You can think they're(objects are) created in a fictional factory in your simulator. The blueprint of object is the "class", and is called `encapsulation`.

Each of these objects are bound to your world, probably through some sort of highly mathematical Half-Life-2(source) level Physics engine. You wouldn't want to code the "physics" for each class. Instead you would inherit from a class(or interface) "IPhysics". And then whenever you change the gravity from 10.0 to 15.0, this value is propagated throughout the "world" scenario. This is `inheritance`.

Each object in your game, say Half-Life-2, Gordon Freeman can at the same time, act as a "Player" and "Can-Be-Scripted" if you know what I mean. This is polymorphism. One object acting in different types.

So you see, this is pretty easy(and terribly EFFICIENT) to model and present the fictional game in OOP.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't terribly inefficient. And you definitely need an introduction to OOP of some sort. Maybe even [something online](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22769/Introduction-to-Object-Oriented-Programming-Concep)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

As the project becomes larger having one global anything will cause a vast list of problems. It's also not particularly inefficient to traverse a few pointers. Worry about efficiency in the right areas, areas that you have proven by running tests are inefficient, and try and maintain code clarity and separation at all times.

If you're worried about inefficiency why not knock together a test app that has exactly that kind of structure and time how long it takes to do all that dereferencing. You'll find it insignificant to, say, building up the list of polys in sight.

The only way you'll see the benefit of having well encapsulated non-global objects will be as your project grows and you change things around.

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple big tenants of OO design: in particular Code-Reuse/modularity and scope/isolation. Globals are generally frowned upon these days because they just don't scale well to large development efforts and always end up causing problems, so OO attempts to limit the scope of any given call to the minimum required to perform the function.

as for Modularity/reuse, the larger a sub-module grows, generally the more specific it becomes, and as such the less likely that it will fit all the purposes it could if it were broken apart into more modular chunks. as a result you spend less time rewriting the same code for a slightly tweaked purpose, which also reduces the adjacent purposes that you might break while implementing code for your new one. that makes it more efficient to implement, though there may or may not be some slight cost at runtime. likely not though. remember, it doesn't take a lick more binary to run Render() whether its defined in a root module or composed several layers deep in a composed object. its still just a function pointer.

these are just general concepts, so take what you like.

hope that helps.